# Python django выводит ошибку:django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ОШИБКА: столбец "group_id" содержит значения NULL

Tags: django, postgresql

Я работал над проектом и все было хорошо,я работал с моделями,и в один момент django начал выводить ошибку:Python django выводит ошибку:django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ОШИБКА:  столбец "group_id" содержит значения NULL.Я почистил модели и создал новые , но это ошибка вылазит каждый раз.Работаю на бд postgresql.В чем проблема?

Comment: миграции удаляли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте вернуть миграции к начальному состоянию

```
python manage.py migrate 'имя_приложения' zero --fake
```

Создать новый файл миграции

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Запустить новую миграцию с параметром fake, чтобы добавить информацию о миграции в базу данных,не изменяя структуру базы данных

```
python manage.py migrate 'имя_приложения' --fake
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,помогло

Comment: @ДаниилПоздеев не за что. Отметьте ответ как решение тогда)