# Миграции не работают Django

Tags: mysql, база-данных, django, миграция

Накосячил с БД и всё полетело. Хочу вернуть всё на место, но при попытке вызвать

```
python manage.py migrate students 0001
```

чтобы сделать самые первые миграции выдаёт ошибку

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'pystudent.students_grade' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: попробуйте так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090492/355827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью команды `python manage.py sqlmigrate students 0001`
выполнил SQL запрос и всё заработало